# How to write test case for the require function

Tags: blockchain, mocha, solidity-0.8.x

```
**Contract**   

     contract ProductNFT is ERC721{ 
        
        uint public totalSupply;
        address public wadmin;
        address public brand;
        address public designer;
        string public _baseURIextended; // Base URI
        constructor(uint _id, address _brand,address _admin,address   _tokenSymbol) ERC721(_tokenName,_tokenSymbol) {
        id =_id;
        brand = _brand;
        admin = _admin;
        tokenSymbol = _tokenSymbol;
}

        function setBaseURI(string memory baseURI_) external  {
        require (msg.sender == wadmin || msg.sender == brand && totalSupply == 0,"Base URI cannot be changed after minting");
        _baseURIextended = baseURI_;
    }
```

**I am trying to write the test case for it**

```
const ProductNFT = artifacts.require('ProductNFT');
require('chai')
  .use(require('chai-as-promised'))
  .should()



contract('ProductNFT', (accounts) => {
    let contract_ProductNFT 

    console.log("accounts>>>>>",accounts)
    let owner = accounts[0]
    let account_brandwallet = accounts[1]
    let designer_address = accounts[2]

    
    
    before(async ()=> {
        console.log("Bye--------------")
        contract_ProductNFT = await ProductNFT.deployed() // copy of abi 
        // console.log('ABI....of contract_ProductNFT....',contract_ProductNFT)
    })
    
    describe("set BaseURI ", async() => {
    it('',async() => {
        //test code
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expect a function call to revert and assert the error message upon reverting as follows:

```
await expect(<YOUR FUNCTION CALL HERE>).to.be.revertedWith(<YOUR `REQUIRE` ERROR MESSAGE HERE>);
```

For your example above, the test would be something along the lines of:

```
...
describe("set BaseURI ", async() => {
    it('',async() => {
        //test code
        // assuming total supply > 0 at this point int time:
        await expect(contract_ProductNFT.setBaseURI("https://...", { from: brand })).to.be.revertedWith("Base URI cannot be changed after minting");
    })
```

Comment: after running the above code I am getting Error: Invalid Chai property: revertedWith

Answer (score 1):

**I was trying to access state variable totalSupply to pass my test case by checking if it equals 0 or not **

> My test script would be like this

```
describe("setBaseURI ", async() => {
        it('sets the base URI & Check one who execute this f() is Wakawadmin_addr or brand_address & totalSupply is 0 ',async() => {
            try{
                const result = await contract_ProductNFT.setBaseURI('www.example.com', {'from': account_brandwallet})
                truffleAssert.eventEmitted(result, '_totalSupply', (event) =>{
                    return event.total_Supply == 0;
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(`${account_brandwallet} is not ownerAddress  & Brand Address   !!! Please change the account`);
            }
            
           
        })
    })
```

and inside my.sol file you need to write event function

```
contract ProductNFT is ERC721{ 
        
        uint public totalSupply;
        address public wadmin;
        address public brand;
        address public designer;
        string public _baseURIextended; // Base URI
        constructor(uint _id, address _brand,address _admin,address   _tokenSymbol) ERC721(_tokenName,_tokenSymbol) {
        id =_id;
        brand = _brand;
        admin = _admin;
        tokenSymbol = _tokenSymbol;
}
        event _totalSupply (uint total_Supply);
        function setBaseURI(string memory baseURI_) external  {
        require (msg.sender == wadmin || msg.sender == brand && totalSupply == 0,"Base URI cannot be changed after minting");
        _baseURIextended = baseURI_;
        emit _totalSupply (totalSupply);
    }
```